# Displaying State of an Async Api call in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, google-books-api

This question builds on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70663447/12939143). Basically Im making an async call to the Google Books Api when a certain button is pressed. While I got the call working when its a method of the View however I want to overlay an activity indicator while it's loading. Hence I tried making an ObservableObject to make the call instead but Im not sure how to do it.

Here's what I have so far:

```swift
class GoogleBooksApi: ObservableObject {
    
    enum LoadingState<Value> {
        case loading(Double)
        case loaded(Value)
    }
    
    @Published var state: LoadingState<GoogleBook> = .loading(0.0)
    
    enum URLError : Error {
        case badURL
    }

    func fetchBook(id identifier: String) async throws {
        var components = URLComponents(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes")
        components?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "isbn=\(identifier)")]
        guard let url = components?.url else { throw URLError.badURL }
        self.state = .loading(0.25)
        
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        self.state = .loading(0.75)
        self.state = .loaded(try JSONDecoder().decode(GoogleBook.self, from: data))
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var author: String = ""
    @State var total: String = ""
    
    @State var code = "ISBN"
    
    @ObservedObject var api: GoogleBooksApi
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Name: \(name)")
            Text("Author: \(author)")
            Text("total: \(total)")

            Button(action: {
                code = "978-0441013593"
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await api.fetchBook(id: code)
                        let fetchedBooks = api.state
                        let book = fetchedBooks.items[0].volumeInfo
                        name = book.title
                        author = book.authors?[0] ?? ""
                        total = String(book.pageCount!)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }, label: {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            })
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - GoogleBook
struct GoogleBook: Codable {
    let kind: String
    let totalItems: Int
    let items: [Item]
}

// MARK: - Item
struct Item: Codable {
    let id, etag: String
    let selfLink: String
    let volumeInfo: VolumeInfo
}

// MARK: - VolumeInfo
struct VolumeInfo: Codable {
    let title: String
    let authors: [String]?
    let pageCount: Int?
    let categories: [String]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title, authors
        case pageCount, categories
    }
}
```

and this is what works without the loading states:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var author: String = ""
    @State var total: String = ""
    
    @State var code = "ISBN"
    
    enum URLError : Error {
        case badURL
    }

    private func fetchBook(id identifier: String) async throws -> GoogleBook {
        guard let encodedString = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q={\(identifier)}"
                                  .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
              let url = URL(string: encodedString) else { throw URLError.badURL}
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(GoogleBook.self, from: data)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Name: \(name)")
            Text("Author: \(author)")
            Text("total: \(total)")

            Button(action: {
                code = "978-0441013593"
                Task {
                    do {
                        let fetchedBooks = try await fetchBook(id: code)
                        let book = fetchedBooks.items[0].volumeInfo
                        name = book.title
                        author = book.authors?[0] ?? ""
                        total = String(book.pageCount!)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }, label: {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            })
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - GoogleBook
struct GoogleBook: Codable {
    let kind: String
    let totalItems: Int
    let items: [Item]
}

// MARK: - Item
struct Item: Codable {
    let id, etag: String
    let selfLink: String
    let volumeInfo: VolumeInfo
}

// MARK: - VolumeInfo
struct VolumeInfo: Codable {
    let title: String
    let authors: [String]?
    let pageCount: Int?
    let categories: [String]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title, authors
        case pageCount, categories
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go a step further and add `idle` and `failed` states.

Then instead of throwing an error change the state to `failed` and pass the error description. I removed the `Double` value from the `loading` state to just show a spinning `ProgressView`

```
@MainActor
class GoogleBooksApi: ObservableObject {
    
    enum LoadingState {
        case idle
        case loading
        case loaded(GoogleBook)
        case failed(Error)
    }
    
    @Published var state: LoadingState = .idle
    
    func fetchBook(id identifier: String) async {
        var components = URLComponents(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes")
        components?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "isbn=\(identifier)")]
        guard let url = components?.url else { state = .failed(URLError(.badURL)); return }
        self.state = .loading
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(GoogleBook.self, from: data)
            self.state = .loaded(response)
        } catch {
            state = .failed(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In the view you have to `switch` on the `state` and show different views.
And – very important – you have to declare the observable object as `@StateObject`. This is a very simple implementation

```
struct ContentView: View {
      @State var code = "ISBN"
      
      @StateObject var api = GoogleBooksApi()
      
      var body: some View {
          VStack {
              switch api.state {
                  case .idle: EmptyView()
                  case .loading: ProgressView()
                  case .loaded(let books):
                      if let info = books.items.first?.volumeInfo {
                          Text("Name: \(info.title)")
                          Text("Author: \(info.authors?.joined(separator: ", ") ?? "")")
                          Text("total: \(books.totalItems)")
                      }
                  case .failed(let error): 
                      if error is DecodingError {
                          Text(error.description)
                      } else {
                          Text(error.localizedDescription)
                      }
              }

              Button(action: {
                  code = "978-0441013593"
                  Task {
                    await api.fetchBook(id: code)
                  }
              }, label: {
                  Rectangle()
                      .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                      .foregroundColor(.blue)
              })
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're not initializing the `GoogleBooksApi`.

```
@ObservedObject var api: GoogleBooksApi
```

neither any init where it can be modified.

Other than that - I'd suggest using `@StateObject` (provided you deployment target is minimum iOS 14.0). Using `ObservableObject` might lead to multiple initializations of the `GoogleBooksApi` (whereas you need only once)

> You should use `@StateObject` for any observable properties that you
> initialize in the view that uses it. If the `ObservableObject` instance
> is created externally and passed to the view that uses it mark your
> property with `@ObservedObject`.